# Failed to use git pull for a branch

Tags: git, git-flow

I get this error msg from git when I try to do git pull:

```
$ git branch
  develop
  feature/add-extra-student-automatically-to-cround
* feature/adjust-my-settings-as-pm
  feature/change_order_course_code_name
  feature/link_my_settings_to_create_survey
  feature/moodle-turnitin-message
  feature/remove_wrong_text_in_notifications
  feature/survey-reports_show-coursename-better-in-survey
  feature/yellow-box-course-schedule
  master
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:/etc/proj/social$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/adjust-my-settings-as-pm
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Your branch has no upstream (remote tracking) branch configured. Either configure one like told by Git, or be explicit about which branch to fetch and merge (like told by Git).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
git pull origin <your_branch>
```

In order to prevent this, use `-u` when you push in order to:

> Set up `<branchname>'s` tracking information so `<upstream>` is considered
>   `<branchname>'s` upstream branch. If no `<branchname>` is specified,     then it defaults to the current branch.

It'll simply tell `git` where to look when it tries to pull for that branch.